# Routes and Models issue on a Rails Join Table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm creating an app that allows users to create custom itineraries for places in my neighborhood.  Each place is stored on a places table and is associated with a place_id.  Currently the places are associated with users through itineraries as a join table.  This works fine, but I want to allow users to sign_in and be directed to a view which will list all their itineraries.  To do this, I will need to create a new instance of an itinerary through a set of user params that has a title and is associated with a user_id.  Then, the user can add place_ids to that instance of the itinerary.  Unfortunately, I cannot wrap my head around how this should be routed in active record.  Can anyone help me figure out how to structure this, so it will work, because everything I try keeps returning the error: No route matches [GET] "/create_itinerary".

Itinerary Model

```
class Itinerary < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :place
```

end

Itinerary Controller

```
class ItinerariesController < ApplicationController
def add_place
    # current_user
    @place = Place.find(params[:id])
    @itenerary = @place.itineraries.create(user_id: current_user.id)

    redirect_to :back
end

def index
    @itinerary_places = current_user.places
end

def show
    @itinerary_places = current_user.places
end

def new
    @itinerary_new = Itinerary.new(params[:itinerary])

    redirect_to create_itinerary_path
end

def create
    itinerary = Itinerary.new(itinerary_params)
    itinerary.user_id = session[:user_id]
    itinerary.save
end

private

def itinerary_params
    params.require(:itinerary).permit(:title)
end

    end
```

Ininerary (new.html.erb)

```
<%= form_for @itinerary_new, url: {action: "create"}, html: {} do |f| %>

<%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Name Your New Itinerary" %>

<%= f.submit :class => "user_submit" %>
```

itineraries routing

```
get "/itinerary_new", to: "itineraries#new"
get "/itinerary_portal", to: "itineraries#index"
get "/itinerary", to: "itineraries#show"
get "/add_place/:id", to: "itineraries#add_place"
get "/delete_itinerary", to: "itineraries#destroy"
post "/create_itinerary", to: "itinerary#create"
```

The Schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170402040005) do

create_table "itineraries", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer  "user_id"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.integer  "place_id"
 t.string   "title"

 end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when your visit `/itinerary_new`, it redirect to `/create_itinerary`. Then the http method mismatch, because the `create_itinerary` only accept `post`, no `get`.

Remove `redirect_to create_itinerary_path` in `new` action. This sentence is meaningless and wrong.